# Max report body height

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reporting, rdlc

My app generates .RDLC report dynamically. On big amount of data the report rendering engine throws the exception below:
[image: Error]

Report structure:
[image: Report structure]

Is there a way to avoid this limitation? 
In my opinion report with 1155.7 cm height of body is not so big (without header and footer only about 40 pages).

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Did not find better solution than validating of report body height during generation . When body height > 1155 cm - terminate report generation and show message to user with advice to change filter options (reduce date range, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue before. Just try control the row height. for example, regularly if the row height is 0.5cm, then it would be maximum rows 2311. In case, if you report row is greater than this, you could dynamically set the row height as 0.2cm, then it would let you output 5778 rows.